# Auxiliary constructor invoking what seems to be an undefined method

Tags: scala, constructor-overloading

New to OOP. The following scala code is used in Diplomacy, a parameter negotiation framework.

```
package chipsalliance.rocketchip

object config { 
  //OP: Definition of View, Field omitted
  abstract class Parameters extends View {
    final def ++ (x: Parameters): Parameters =
      new ChainParameters(this, x)

    final def alter(f: (View, View, View) => PartialFunction[Any,Any]): Parameters =
      Parameters(f) ++ this

    final def alterPartial(f: PartialFunction[Any,Any]): Parameters =
      Parameters((_,_,_) => f) ++ this

    final def alterMap(m: Map[Any,Any]): Parameters =
      new MapParameters(m) ++ this

    protected[config] def chain[T](site: View, tail: View, pname: Field[T]): Option[T]
    protected[config] def find[T](pname: Field[T], site: View) = chain(site, new TerminalView, pname)
  }

  object Parameters {
    def empty: Parameters = new EmptyParameters
    def apply(f: (View, View, View) => PartialFunction[Any,Any]): Parameters = new PartialParameters(f)
  }

  class Config(p: Parameters) extends Parameters {
    def this(f: (View, View, View) => PartialFunction[Any,Any]) = this(Parameters(f))

    protected[config] def chain[T](site: View, tail: View, pname: Field[T]) = p.chain(site, tail, pname)
    override def toString = this.getClass.getSimpleName
    def toInstance = this
  }

  // Internal implementation:
  // OP: Some private classes omitted  
  private class PartialParameters(f: (View, View, View) => PartialFunction[Any,Any]) extends Parameters {
    protected[config] def chain[T](site: View, tail: View, pname: Field[T]) = {
      val g = f(site, this, tail)
      if (g.isDefinedAt(pname)) Some(g.apply(pname).asInstanceOf[T]) else tail.find(pname, site)
    }
  }
}
```

As I understand it, the auxiliary constructor of Config class (that uses a partial function literal as the argument) invokes the primary constructor (that uses the Parameter class's companion object's apply method) which has to return a parameter object (or class?) by calling PartialParameters(f). As I see it, the protected method, chain, is just the concrete implementation of the abstract chain in Parameters superclass; and won't be evaluated (as it's not a constructor) when PartialParameters(f) is created/called/invoked. So, where does PartialParameters(f) evaluate?

I appreciate any hints or links to materials if I'm fundamentally missing something.

Comment: The full code is here: https://github.com/chipsalliance/api-config-chipsalliance/blob/d619ca850846d2ec36da64bf8a28e7d9a3d9ed1b/design/craft/src/config/Config.scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is correct, so `new Config(f)` is basically a shorthand for `new Config(new PartialParameters(f))`. When that is evaluated/executed, you have a `Config` object wrapping a `PartialParameters` object, but the parameters' `chain` method is not invoked by its constructor.

Statements/expressions in Scala are by default eagerly executed/evaluated, just like in any other imperative language. In Scala, however, you can also achieve lazy evaluation. For that function parameters must be explicitly marked as [by name](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html) by prepending `=>` to their types.

It's not clear to me, what you're referring to as "undefined method". Edit your question if you can clarify that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. "When that is evaluated/executed, ..." -- Where does it get evaluated?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Does that answer your question?